# Requests to AWS's RDS auth token endpoint are too slow

Tags: .net, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am using IAM authentication (with STS) for my Postgres RDS on AWS.
In order to login to my DB, my .NET app is using the following code to request the RDS auth token to the regional endpoint (as instructed on the AWS docs):

```
var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnectionString)
{
    ProvidePasswordCallback = (host, port, _, username) =>
    {
            var region = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(EC2InstanceMetadata.Region.SystemName);
            return RDSAuthTokenGenerator.GenerateAuthToken(region, host, port, username);
    }
};
```

The problem is that these request are **REALLY** slow - averaging 300+ milliseconds.

This is way too slow for a token request and it slows down my application quite a bit as this request is being sent for every physical connection that's being created by the app.

I've tried adding the following options to the connection string to decrease the number of requests but it doesn't seem to have a big enough effect:

```
Minimum Pool Size=1;Connection Idle Lifetime=1800
```

Any creative ideas before I go back to using a plain old password?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have configured a pool 5-10 connections and cached the token. Still, when the token expires, the next connection will take more than 2 seconds. I am actively seeking a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

According to the source code, `RDSAuthTokenGenerator.GenerateAuthToken` generates a token that is [valid for 15 minutes](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Services/RDS/Custom/Util/RDSAuthTokenGenerator.cs#L144).

It is not meant to be an auth token that is generated on every request, but a token that is cached.

Start caching your token. The method call just does a simple HTTP request.

Comment: This will only help decrease the number of requests within a 15 minutes window. My logs show that connections are being created every 30 mins on average which means that caching won't be effective as the token will expire by the time I need to reuse it.

Comment: @DannyIdlis that has nothing to do with RDS - you will need to configure your connection pool appropriately within your application. the question is regarding the requests taking too long and the answer is that the requests shouldn't be so frequent. you're conflating 2 questions into 1.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Even using a cache, the first connection will still take more than 2 seconds. For my system, it happens once a day and is still annoying. Should I use a cron job to frequently check if the auth token expires or not, before customer hits the service and experience the slowness?